# how to automatize/create sub-domains with boto for amazon Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, amazon-route53

Is there a way to use the amazon boto(python tool) API for Route53 in order to create custom subdomains for a multi-tenant application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  boto.route53.connection.create_hosted_zone() appears to be what you want.